# sql syntax: I want to limit colmn value into a specific list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named **`project`**.

In that table a column named `project_statu`.

So what I wanna do is limit that column into a specific list as (

- 'finished',
- 'in progress',
- 'not finished'

).

What I tried but didn't work:

```
update table project check project_statut in ('finished','not finished','in progress');
```

Comment: is there any other table that will be join your project table?

Comment: Please use punctuation; your question is one single sentence, which is difficult to read.

Comment: MySQL has enum & set types - they could be used to do what you want - but they have their own disadvantages. You could make a second linked table with allowed values.

Comment: Formatted this simple question for quick understanding

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your table using `Check` Constraint

```
CREATE TABLE Project
(
P_Id number,
project_status  varchar(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT chk_st CHECK (project_status='finished' or project_status= 'in progress' or project_status='not finished')
)
```

**Update**

For more help please visit [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp)

Hope it will help.

Comment: Unfortunately MySQL does not support SQL check constraints. You can define them in your DDL query for compatibility reasons but they are just ignored.

Comment: then you can create trigger for that.

Comment: Yes. You need to adopt `trigger` for that

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple ways in MySQL.  The first is to create a ProjectStatuses table and a foreign key constraint:

```
create table ProjectStatuses (ProjectStatus varchar(255));

insert into ProjectStatuses(ProjectStatus)
     values ('finished'), ('in progress'), ('not finished');
```

Then use a foreign key constraint:

```
alter table project
    add constraint fk_project_projectstatuses
         foreign key project_status references ProjectStatuses(ProjectStatus);
```

Another method is MySQL is to use the `enum` type.  You can read about that [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html).